# Disable Protected mode in Internet Explorer Security options

Tags: security, internet-explorer, group-policy

I need a small help to disable the protected mode in IE 8. Here is my scenario.

I have admin rights on my machine, but I am not able to disable Protected mode. When I Run IE as Administrator also, I could not able to disable it. When I asked our helpdesk, they said those options are enabled at the server side and they cannot override on machine. They asked me that I can try it myself. I am wondering is there any trick to do?

This is very important for me because I need to run Selenium Automation tool which I our application requires IE only. In order to run this tool I need to disable this Protected mode.

Please Help Me......

[image: Internet Security Options]

Comment: group policy settings will override local settings. Don't think you can do anything about this

Comment: Is this a company PC?? If yes, then your helpdesk might be telling you the truth.... Companies usually does this kind of stuff, to prevent employees from altering the settings..

Comment: @Sathya, helpdesk tried using group policy settings by creating a new group, but it never worked. -Vineet:Yes this is company issed PC, but they are happy to help me for altering these settings. Do you think logging it as Administrator will work instead of my user name

Comment: If they created a new group where was it in the AD tree? It might still be inheriting down the original settings. Try putting your pc in a seperate group and turning off inheritence, then only apply the essential GPO's without the IE policy (I'm assuming a lot here BTW)

Comment: @Joe, I can have that group policy settings privileges. Do you think editing the file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\CUSTOM\seczones.inf may help? I need only the Internet zone should be disabled.

Comment: Hi Vikram,i don't know about that file sorry. Are you saying you have access to the GroupPolicy settings for the company. Including the ability to move computers between containers and modify the settings for containers? if so then simply create a OU off the OU your PC currently sits in, move your computer to this 'child' OU, and add a GPO in this OU to turn off IE protected mode. This will override the inherited settings for that OU, which contains only your computer while leaving intact all the other settings inherited down.

Comment: Sorry my bad typo error. I dont have group policy settings. But I got an Idea for changing it by registry editor. Currently searching for the right key to disable it in Registry editor

Comment: you could try creating a new local user separate from cooperate account.

Answer (score 0):

if its enforced through Group Policy changing the registry on the machine is useless.  It will only temporarily fix the problem and the next time your machine updates it will pull the policy back down and reset the registry.  This issue needs to be fixed at the server level.

Another thing you can try just incase its a image setting is open gpedit.msc and look at the local system policies.   IE options are located under Computer Configuration/administrative templates/ windows components/internet explorer.

If the setting there is greyed out and cant be changed then the server is passing the policy and it will need to be addressed by the server.  The only other way to stop the server from setting this is to remove your system from the company domain.